# Next.js - trying to implement an initial loading screen but content flashes for a moment before loader starts

Tags: next.js, loader

I would like to implement a loading screen on first render in next.js but when I load the page the body content flashes for a moment before the loader starts. I'm not sure what should I write differently. If I change the initial state to true that doesn't seem to work either because then the wrapper styles for the loader won't apply and instead I get a blank html page with the spinner on the top left corner.

_app.js

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <ThemeProvider theme={dark}>
          <GlobalStyles />
          <Component {...pageProps} />;
        </ThemeProvider>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Loader div style:

```
.loader-wrapper{
  width:100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.body};
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Loader Component

```
export const Loader = () => {
  return (
    <div className='loader-wrapper'>
      <Oval
        ariaLabel='loading-indicator'
        height={100}
        width={100}
        strokeWidth={2}
        color='#32ffa9'
        secondaryColor='#1f1f1fdc'
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because `useEffect` called after component rendered.

Life cycle:

1- Initial state of `isLoading = false` `<ThemeProvider />` rendered (body content flashes for a moment)

2- useEffect called and `isLoading = true`

3- Component re-rendered but this time it will render `<Loader />`

4- 3 second later setTimeout callback called `isLoading = false`

5- Component re-rendered and it will render `<ThemeProvider />` again

So you should make your inital `isLoading = true`, I couldn't understand the issue "wrapper styles for the loader won't apply." can you describe it more?

I made [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-70897098-lbqnl?file=/src/App.js) example for you which I think works as you want (it's not NextJS app but since all the code is pure React it will work on both)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the issue still remains if I set the state to true. I added additional code of the wrapper style and loader component. So instead of getting the loader div style I get a blank html page with the spinner in the top left corner.

Comment: It's fixed :) . I received a blank page when state is true because I've put the styling in the globastyles instead of the loader component.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it, I'm not sure what "<GlobalStyles />" contains but you can also add your conditional rendering inside <ThemeProvider /> so maybe your globalstyles will apply all the time :)

Comment: Your example does not handle clearTimeout,

it might be better to do this way: 

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(pageLoader, 1000);
    return clearTimeout(pageLoader);
  }, []);